# How to use GET/POST without the input argument

Tags: php, html, r

I use rapache module to build a web site base on r statistic programing language.
The way to pass variables to r are by using the GET/POST methods.

But I want to insert value with PHP to the $_POST variable and then to pass it to r.

Is there a way to use GET/POST without the "input" argument. I mean can I give the variable a value and not to wait for the client to make an action, for example the press the submit button?

Thanks for any help,

yoni.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HTTP extension](http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) in PHP to create your own POST to your r platform. Specifically you can use [HttpRequest::addPostFields](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-addpostfields.php) to add post fields to that request.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I'm new to web , and I found the links difficult to understand.
Can you pls write an example on how can it be use?

Answer (score 0):

Once again, don't use PHP. RApache provides POST and GET superglobals similar to PHP. All you'll have to do is to massage them within R script file. Parameters from POST/GET requests are wrapped into R list (generic vectors), so you can easily manipulate them within R.

Please put a reproducible example, so folks can actually see what are you up to.